# Bundle Identifier for Keyboard Extension

Tags: swift, custom-keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

I am working on a keyboard extension I have registered the bundle identifier of container app on developer.apple.com. is it necessary to register the bundle identifer of extension app on developer.apple.com ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to even register the containing app , you can use automatic signing , but if you need to go manually , yes you have to register the extensions also

Comment: client have provided his own bundle identifier so, I have to change

Answer (score 1):

if you have enabled auto signing than just add the bundle id in the extention target & that will automatically got register at developer.apple.com. If you are manually processing the signing than you have to register that id on developer.apple.com